# Getting an object from array member in class VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a class object called cSchedule which contains a member pTimeline which is an array of cDay objects. I'm trying to use pTimeline's Get Property to return the cDay object at a particular index but I get the following error **"Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"**.

I'm calling this function from my main module as follows

```
Dim TestDay As cDay
Set TestDay = TestSchedule.Timeline(1)
```

I've verified that the TestSchedule contains all the proper data, so the issue is with how I'm trying to get a reference to the cDay object at a particular index of pTimeline.

```
' Class Module: cSchedule

Private pTimeline() As cDay
Private pFitness As Double
Private pMap As Collection
'Number of units the timeline is divided into. E.g if weeks, pNumTimeUnits should be 52*numYears
Private pNumTimeUnits As Integer


''''''''''''''''''''''
' Timeline property
''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get Timeline(Optional argIndex As Variant) As Variant
    If IsMissing(argIndex) Then
        Timeline = pTimeline
    Else
        Dim selectedDay As Variant
        selectedDay = pTimeline(argIndex).Copy
        Set Timeline = selectedDay
    End If
End Property
Public Property Let Timeline(Optional argIndex As Variant, arrValue As Variant)
    Dim arrLength As Integer
    Dim intIndex As Integer

    ' Resize array if incoming list of activities is greater than current
    arrLength = (UBound(arrValue) - LBound(arrValue) + 1)
    If arrLength <> pNumTimeUnits Then
        ReDim Preserve pTimeline(arrLength)
        pNumTimeUnits = arrLength
    End If
    pTimeline = arrValue
End Property
```

Would anyone be able to provide insight into what I'm doing wrong and what the correct way is to get an object from a class member containing an array of objects?

Comment: does **Set TestDay = TestSchedule.Timeline.Item(1)** improve things ??

Comment: You should include the `cDay` class. You should almost also ecplicitly type you variables whenever possible.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I believe the .Item is only for collections whereas I'm using an array so I don't think that will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there's a fair bit not quite right about your code.

One of the problems is that you have arrays and classes being returned within the same property, which isn't great practice anyway but also forces you to return the property as a `Variant` which sometimes needs to be assigned using the keyword `Set` because the returned value is sometimes an object.

A better way might be to have two properties: one which gets and sets the array, and one which gets a single member of that array. An abbreviated version of your *cSchedule* class, then, might looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private pTimelines() As cDay
Private pTimeline() As cDay
Private pNumTimeUnits As Long

Public Property Get Timelines() As Variant
    Timelines = pTimelines
End Property

Public Property Let Timelines(RHS As Variant)
    pTimelines = RHS
    pNumTimeUnits = UBound(RHS) - LBound(RHS) + 1
End Property

Public Property Get TimelineAt(idx As Long) As cDay
    Set TimelineAt = pTimelines(idx)
End Property
```

Secondly, your `Timeline` setting routine might not be doing what you think it's doing. Even though you use `Redim Preserve` to resize your array, the later line `pTimeline = arrValue` will overwrite and, indeed, resize that array. So all of your code above that line is redundant.

Finally, I suspect the code throwing the error is in the line `selectedDay = pTimeline(argIndex).Copy`. Without seeing your `cDay` class, we can't say for sure, but if that `Copy` function returns a `cDay` class then you'd need the `Set` keyword - again, it's one of the problems you encounter if you use `Variant`s too often.

Personally, I'd define `pTimelines` as a `Collection`, but in any event, some sample module code to show you how the above could work is shown below:

```
Dim testSchedule As cSchedule
Dim t() As cDay
Dim i As Long

Set testSchedule = New cSchedule

ReDim t(51)
For i = 0 To 51
    Set t(i) = New cDay
    t(i).TheDate = DateAdd("w", i, DateSerial(2018, 1, 1))
Next

testSchedule.Timelines = t

Debug.Print testSchedule.TimelineAt(0).TheDate
```

For the purposes of this demo, I've written the `cDay` class as below, but this example doesn't implement the `MyCopy` function:

```
Option Explicit

Private pTheDate As Date

Public Property Get TheDate() As Date
    TheDate = pTheDate
End Property

Public Property Let TheDate(RHS As Date)
    pTheDate = RHS
End Property

Public Function MyCopy() As cDay
    Set MyCopy = New cDay
    MyCopy.TheDate = pTheDate
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @Ambie, I solved the issue by separating it into two properties - the Get TimelineAt does the job really well. I've realized this is a better approach compared to using the MyCopy() function since I just need a reference to the object and don't need to go through the trouble of creating a copy.